# differentiation between using Hellinger and Normalize when using mvpart package to make MRT

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, data-transformation

i just tried to analyzed data using mvpart, then when i use decostand Hellinger and Normalize ,they gave different result. so whats the meaning of them

Comment: If you are going to get a helpful answer you need to give us much, much more detail by editing your post to explain what you think they are doing and exactly how the results differ. Also try to make clear which part is a statistical question as if this is about R programming it would usually be considered off-topic here.